# my mini project

Tags: bookmarks, syntax-highlighting

I am doing my mini project in Ubuntu. Its actually a text editor like Gedit. I am done with basic elements like cut copy paste delete and save..can I get the source code for bookmarking and syntax highlighting. I am doing it in Java with net beans IDE.

Comment: I think this is better suited for [so], the syntax highlighting in gedit comes from the GtkSourceView library. Read [SourceView API](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/sourceview/SourceView.html), I think you need to install `libgtksourceview-3.0-dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the gedit source code itself. You can find it [here](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/).